# Problema para tomar la geoposicion en edificios. Android Studio

Tags: android, geolocalización, gps

Buen día!
Les consulto, estoy desarrollando una app en donde tomos los puntos gps con gps_PROVIDER, hasta el momento todo perfecto, pero cuando quiero tomarlo dentro de un edificio no puedo hacerlo.
Sé que al trabajar con satelites es complicado tomarlo por lo cual me gustaria saber como debo hacer en caso de que sino lo toma por gps_provide en una sierta cantidad de intento lo pueda tomar de otra manera y que manera me recomiendan que sea precisa a tal punto que el margen de error sea de hasta 15 mts. Desde ya les agradezco y muestro como va el codigo. Saludos.

```
 intentos = 0;
    cantidad = 1;
    precision = 100;
    precisionIngresa= 100;

    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());
    //if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
    //       ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            precisionIngresa = location.getAccuracy();


            //if (location != null) {

            if (precisionIngresa < precision){

                precision = precisionIngresa;

            }



            if (precision < 10 && intentos <= 10 && cantidad == 1) {
                //    Location location = getLocation(this, locationManager, provider);

                direccion.set_latitude(location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) : "");
                direccion.set_longitude(location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()) : "");
                direccion.setLocationAcuracy(location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()) : "");
                direccion.setLocationProvider(location != null ? location.getProvider() : "");
                direccion.setLocationTime(location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getTime()) : "");

                //}
                db.updateContact(direccion);
                cantidad = 2;
            }else if (intentos == 11 && cantidad == 1 && precision <= 15){


                direccion.set_latitude(location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) : "");
                direccion.set_longitude(location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()) : "");
                //  direccion.setLocationAcuracy(location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()) : "");
                direccion.setLocationAcuracy(location != null ? String.valueOf(precision):"");
                direccion.setLocationProvider(location != null ? location.getProvider() : "");
                direccion.setLocationTime(location != null ? String.valueOf(location.getTime()) : "");

                //}
                db.updateContact(direccion);
                cantidad = 2;
            }
            if (cantidad == 2 || intentos == 11){
                locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                locationListener = null;
            }

            intentos =intentos + 1;



        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    //return;
    //}
    int persmissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AddressScreen.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: El error es que me saca de la aplicacion porque no me trae una ubicacion gps dentro de ese rango de 15 metros dentro de un edificio. Por eso busco poner como principal la geoposicion por GPS_provider y si eso falla buscar otra forma de tomar la geo que sea precisa

Comment: Utilizas el simulador o en el dispositivo?.

Comment: dispositivo directamente.